# Creating React App npx create-react-app react-task-tracker

Tags: reactjs

[image: Code Module not found]

I am creating new react app but this error shows. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new react app using the same project name and it worked fine. From my experience, I had this incident, when I had an & in my project path.

If this is not the case please confirm where you installed your node and where you are installing this react app.

Comment: Problem is solved. I deleted previous npm files in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\ folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must have been in your Node JS installation. Delete npm files in AppData\Roaming